# How to determine region from the phone number string?

Tags: ios, swift, phone-number, phonenumberkit

I tried using [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) and couldn't find any proper api which would give me the region name.
I need the region from the phone number so that I can display the appropriate flag. For example using this:

```
  let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse("+12563335956")
  let regionCode = phoneNumberKit.countries(withCode: phoneNumber.countryCode)?.first
  print("region code is: " , regionCode)
```

// US phone number with +1 prefix, but it prints "AG" which is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the country code can tell you which flag to use.

```
let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse("+1 970162651778")
let regionCode = phoneNumberKit.getRegionCode(of: phoneNumber)

print(regionCode) // Optional("US")
```

You can get the country region code using the country code of the phone number.

Comment: Check edited question. This doesn't work. It would print "AG"

Comment: @EnrikQaz it wasn't working because there are multiple countries that use +1, however, country codes that are shared by multiple countries do have a main country, which you can get using `getRegionCode`.